# Export excel not working with row template ejs treegrid syncfusion

Tags: angular, templates, ejs, syncfusion, treegrid

I used ejs treegrid syncfusion to display products with theirs hyrarchies.
Firstable, list display and export excel work perfectly. But when I added row template (Row span in my table), export excel doesn't work.

here my source code :

*product-nomenclature.component.html*

```
<!-- TREE GRID -->
  <ejs-treegrid id='treegrid' 
                #treegrid
                [dataSource]='DATA_TREE_GRID'
                [treeColumnIndex]='0'
                [sortSettings]='sortSettings'
                [allowFiltering]='true'
                [allowSorting]='true'
                childMapping='children'
                [allowPaging]='true'
                [pageSettings]='pageSettings'
                [allowResizing]='true'
                [allowExcelExport]='true'
                (headerCellInfo)='headerCellInfo($event)'
                (toolbarClick)='toolbarClick($event)'
                [toolbar]='toolbarOptions'
                (dataBound)='dataBound()'
                enableHover='true'>
      <e-columns>
          <e-column field='productId' headerText='Product ID' textAlign='left' width=100></e-column>
          <e-column field='label' headerText='Description' textAlign='Left' width=100></e-column>
          <e-column field='typeFabrique' headerText='Product type' textAlign='Center' width=50></e-column>
          <e-column field='coef' headerText='Coefficient' textAlign='Center' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='percentFictive' headerText='% fictive' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='allocations' headerText='Cost center' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='n2tajUoe1' headerText='N2 TAJ_UOE1' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='n2tajUoe2' headerText='N2 TAJ_UOE2' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='n1tajUoe1' headerText='N1 TAJ_UOE1' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
          <e-column field='n1tajUoe2' headerText='N1 TAJ_UOE2' textAlign='Left' width=60></e-column>
      </e-columns>
      <ng-template #rowTemplate let-DATA_TREE_GRID>
          <tr>
              <td class="border">
                  <div matTooltip="{{ DATA_TREE_GRID.productId }}">
                       {{ DATA_TREE_GRID.productId }}
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <div class="custom-4"
                       matTooltip="{{ DATA_TREE_GRID.label }}">
                       {{ DATA_TREE_GRID.label }}
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                <div class="custom-4"
                     matTooltip="{{ DATA_TREE_GRID.typeFabrique }}">
                     {{ DATA_TREE_GRID.typeFabrique }}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                <div class="custom-4"
                     matTooltip="{{ DATA_TREE_GRID.coef }}">
                     {{ DATA_TREE_GRID.coef }}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                <div class="custom-4"
                     matTooltip="{{ DATA_TREE_GRID.percentFictive }}">
                     {{ DATA_TREE_GRID.percentFictive }}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <mat-list>
                      <mat-list-item class="fontsize14" *ngFor="let allocation of DATA_TREE_GRID.allocations; let i = index">
                          <span matTooltip="{{ allocation.costCenterLabel }}">{{ allocation.costCenterLabel }}</span>
                      </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <mat-list>
                    <mat-list-item class="fontsize14" *ngFor="let allocation of DATA_TREE_GRID.allocations; let i = index">
                        <span matTooltip="{{ formatNumber(allocation.n2tajUoe1) }}">{{ formatNumber(allocation.n2tajUoe1) }}</span>
                    </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>  
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <mat-list>
                    <mat-list-item class="fontsize14" *ngFor="let allocation of DATA_TREE_GRID.allocations; let i = index">
                        <span matTooltip="{{ formatNumber(allocation.n2tajUoe2) }}">{{ formatNumber(allocation.n2tajUoe2) }}</span>
                    </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>  
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <mat-list>
                    <mat-list-item class="fontsize14" *ngFor="let allocation of DATA_TREE_GRID.allocations; let i = index">
                        <span matTooltip="{{ formatNumber(allocation.n1tajUoe1) }}">{{ formatNumber(allocation.n1tajUoe1) }}</span>
                    </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>  
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                  <mat-list>
                    <mat-list-item class="fontsize14" *ngFor="let allocation of DATA_TREE_GRID.allocations; let i = index">
                        <span matTooltip="{{ formatNumber(allocation.n1tajUoe2) }}">{{ formatNumber(allocation.n1tajUoe2) }}</span>
                    </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>  
              </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
  </ejs-treegrid>
```

*product-nomenclature.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SortSettingsModel, PageSettingsModel } from '@syncfusion/ej2-treegrid';
import { Tooltip } from '@syncfusion/ej2-popups';
import { PlantSwitcherService } from 'app/pmt/shared/service/plant-switcher';
import { ProductSwitcherService } from 'app/pmt/shared/service/product-switcher';
import { ProductService, IProduct } from 'app/pmt/shared/entity/search-product';
import { combineLatest,
         Observable,
         BehaviorSubject,
         Subject
} from 'rxjs';
import { IPlant } from 'app/shared/model/plant.model';
import { ProductNode } from '../shared/nomenclature-tab/product-node.interface';
import {
    takeUntil,
    filter,
    share,
    switchMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { buildLoader } from 'app/pmt/shared/utils/loading';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { TreeGridComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-treegrid';
import { ToolbarItems } from '@syncfusion/ej2-treegrid';
import { ExcelExportProperties } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids';
import { PhaseSwitcherService } from 'app/pmt/shared/service/phase-switcher';
import { IPhase } from 'app/shared/model/phase.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'pmt-product-nomenclature',
    styleUrls: ['product-nomenclature.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: 'product-nomenclature.component.html'
})
export class ProductNomenclatureComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    public validityDate = new FormControl({value: new Date, disabled: true});

    public plant$: Observable<IPlant>;
    public phase$: Observable<IPhase>;
    public product$: Observable<IProduct>;
    public date$: BehaviorSubject<Date> = new BehaviorSubject<Date>(new Date);
    public deep$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(100);
    public result$: Observable<ProductNode[]>;
    private destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    public loading$: Observable<boolean>;
    public error: any;

    private plant: string;
    private phase: string;

    public DATA_TREE_GRID: ProductNode[];
    public initial = true;

    @ViewChild('treegrid')
    public treeGridObj: TreeGridComponent;
    public toolbarOptions: ToolbarItems[];

    public sortSettings: SortSettingsModel;
    public pageSettings: PageSettingsModel;

    constructor(
        private readonly productSrv: ProductService,
        private readonly plantSwitcherSrv: PlantSwitcherService,
        private readonly phaseSwitcherSrv: PhaseSwitcherService,
        private readonly productSwitcherSrv: ProductSwitcherService,
        private readonly _snackBar: MatSnackBar
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        this.plant$ = this.plantSwitcherSrv.asObservable();
        this.phase$ = this.phaseSwitcherSrv.asObservable();
        this.product$ = this.productSwitcherSrv.asObservable();

        const source$ = combineLatest(
            this.plant$,
            this.product$,
            this.date$,
            this.deep$
        ).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
            filter(([plant, product, date, deep]: [IPlant, IProduct, Date, number]) => !!plant && !!product && !!date && !!deep)
        );

        this.result$ = source$
            .pipe(
                switchMap(([plant, product, date, deep]: [IPlant, IProduct, Date, number]) => {
                    const validityDate =  moment.utc([
                        date.getFullYear(),
                        date.getMonth() + 1,
                        date.getDate()
                    ].join('/'), 'YYYY/MM/DD').toISOString();
                    return this.productSrv.queryNomenclature(plant, product, validityDate, deep);
                }),
                share()
            );

        this.result$
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.DATA_TREE_GRID = res;
                },
                err => {
                    this.error = err.error;
                    this.openSnackBar(err.error.title, 'Dismiss');
                });

        this.loading$ = buildLoader(source$, this.result$);

        this.pageSettings = { pageSize: 10 };
        this.toolbarOptions = ['CollapseAll', 'ExpandAll', 'ExcelExport'];

        this.plant$.subscribe(
            plant => this.plant = !!plant ? plant.plantId.toString() : undefined
        );
        this.phase$.subscribe(
            phase => this.phase = !!phase ? phase.name.toString() : undefined
        );
    }

    public openSnackBar(message: string, action: string): void {
        this._snackBar.open(message, action, {
            duration: 3000,
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method to add header column tooltip
     * @param args
     */
    public headerCellInfo(args) {
        if ( !!args.cell.column.field ) {
            const toolcontent = args.cell.column.headerText;
            const tooltip: Tooltip = new Tooltip({
                content: toolcontent
            });
            tooltip.appendTo(args.node);
        }
    }

    public toolbarClick(args: Object): void {
        if (args['item'].text === 'Expand All') {
            this.treeGridObj.expandAll();
        } else if (args['item'].text === 'Collapse All') {
            this.treeGridObj.collapseAtLevel(0);
        } else if (args['item'].text === 'Excel Export') {
            const excelExportProperties: ExcelExportProperties = {
                fileName: `PMT_Nomenclature_${this.plant}_${this.phase}.xlsx`
            };
            this.treeGridObj.excelExport(excelExportProperties);
        }
    }

    public dataBound(): void {
        if (this.initial === true) {
            this.treeGridObj.collapseAll();
            this.initial = false;
        }
    }

    public formatNumber(nb: number): string {
        return !!nb ? nb.toFixed(6) : '';
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroyed$.next(true);
        this.destroyed$.complete();
    }

}
```

*product-node.interface.ts*

```
import { IAllocation } from './allocation.interface';

export interface ProductNode {
    productId?: string;
    label?: string;
    typeFabrique?: string;
    coef?: number;
    percentFictive?: number;
    allocations?: IAllocation[];
    children?: ProductNode[];
}
```

*allocation.interface.ts*

```
export interface IAllocation {
    costCenterLabel?: string;
    n1tajUoe1?: number;
    n1tajUoe2?: number;
    n1tsoUoe1?: number;
    n1tsoUoe2?: number;
    n2tajUoe1?: number;
    n2tajUoe2?: number;
    n2tsoUoe1?: number;
    n2tsoUoe2?: number;
}
```

Some one can help me ?